# How can I create a fixed length char type table column by createTable in the nodejs knex?

Tags: knex.js, create-table

```js
await knex.schema.createTable('users', (table) => {
    table.integer('age')
    table.string('name', 20)
  })
```

The above code creates the following SQL statement.

```sql
CREATE TABLE "users" (
    age INTEGER,
    name VARCHAR(20)
);
```

Is there a way to make fixed length char table column like `name CHAR(20)` instead of `name VARCHAR(20)`?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using `.specificType`  https://knexjs.org/guide/schema-builder.html#specifictype

e.g.

```js
table.specificType('name', 'CHAR(20)');
```